# Why in Xcode 6 doesn't work Assistant Preview?

Tags: swift, xcode6, preview

Sometimes in Xcode 6 Assistant Editor -> Preview stops working.

Showing just "No selection" even if no errors and Storyboard is ok.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason is "?" (questionmark) in Project's name (maybe there is a bug with other symbols – didn't check it).

You can try to rename Project or just create new one with name without "?" in it.

Comment: Holy balls, how on earth does Apple let these things slip into a release. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You must to **Kill Xcode from processes** for complete and then open it again. You can do it with Activity Monitor o CLI. Voila! - Preview is working again.

Don't just close Xcode keeping the app working. Sometimes also works closing with **CMD + Q.**

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, but fixed it

You must open the xib or storyboard file in both assistant editors. Click the navigation button in the second editor (either the bottom or the right editor, depending on how you stack the assistant editors) and choose Preview to get the preview to appear.

thanks to 
http://meandmark.com/blog/2014/09/xcode-6-no-simulate-document-in-interface-builder/comment-page-1/#comment-2883

Answer (score 0):

I have played with Xcode 6 for a while and I encountered similar problems occasionally. I never used special characters in project or class names but the problem sometimes happens.

Now I have to test all ViewControllers at starting point to see if the Assistant Editor work. If not, I will just delete the class file and recreate the same one, it usually fix the problem.

Hope this can be fixed soon.